# How to resolve this "Target container is not a DOM element." in React with React-Image Gallery/Lightbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lightbox

Im trying to find a solution to what Ive been experiencing with image based galleries (in example lightbox or FancyBox). This error came up after following [this doc](http://neptunian.github.io/react-photo-gallery) and using [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bassi-5vn3lvz2n4?from-embed) as an 
 example.

I have tried using react-images to no avail, the modal doesn't display right, so I tried the links react-photo-gallery and I am encountering this error. Ive tried converting it to a component, and it didn't agree with the App function in the top portion of the file. I also tried creating a html file in my pages directory and added the import link to the illustrationGallery file, but that didn't seem to work.

> My illustrationGallery file

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";
import { illustrations } from "../components/illustrations";
import Artwork from '../pages/gallery';

function App() {
  const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);
  const [viewerIsOpen, setViewerIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const openLightbox = useCallback((event, { photo, index }) => {
    setCurrentImage(index);
    setViewerIsOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const closeLightbox = () => {
    setCurrentImage(0);
    setViewerIsOpen(false);
  };

        return (

            <div>
            <Gallery illustrations={illustrations} onClick={openLightbox} />
            <ModalGateway>
                {viewerIsOpen ? (
                <Modal onClose={closeLightbox}>
                    <Carousel
                    currentIndex={currentImage}
                    views={illustrations.map(x => ({
                        ...x,
                        srcset: x.srcSet,
                        caption: x.title
                    }))}
                    />
                </Modal>
                ) : null}
            </ModalGateway>
            </div>
        );
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("illuGallery"));
```

> Local host window error

```
invariant
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:56
render
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21195
▲ 2 stack frames were expanded.
Module.<anonymous>
src/components/illustrationGallery.js:43
  40 |             </div>
  41 |         );
  42 | }
> 43 | render(<App />, document.getElementById("illuGallery"));
  44 |
```

This error description is towards the top, but there are more

Just trying to achieve something that displays a proper image gallery using react, would it be easier to just make it using another doc or from scratch? Does anyone have any recommendations or answers to help?

Comment: By default react has `root` as `id` in `index.html` file, try this `render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: This didnt seem to do anything, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because:

`document.getElementById("illuGallery")` can not find an element with id `#illuGaller`.

if you are willing to make it work, and this is the only component you actually want react to render.

as from the example of the [codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bassi-5vn3lvz2n4?from-embed).

You go to your template, where react renders the ellement. basically `index.html` or `template.html`, in the example it's `index.html`

And make sure that the root element there which where react will inject your JSX, make sure it has the id `illuGallery`

Comment: How do you change where it renders it? Im just looking to render a gallery on a different page than my ```index.html```

Comment: React only depends on one page to the injection of our Apps.